# Does Cartthrob Subscriptions add channel entries after each occurrence?

Tags: add-on, cartthrob

For the store I'm working on, each standard Cartthrob order creates entries in both the Orders and Purchased Items channels. And I need the Subscriptions orders to do the same after each occurrence.

Does anyone know if Cartthrob Subscriptions does that for EACH occurrence? As far as I could find, the docs only say this...

> CartThrob subscription orders are placed like standard orders, and
>   will show up in the customer's order history. Standard order emails
>   will also be sent in the case of a successful transaction, or in case
>   of failure.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this since I've been using CT Subscriptions with one of my clients for the last 7 months. Each time a subscription is rebilled, an order entry is created in the orders channel. I can't confirm the purchased items channel as I have that disabled since they're not selling digital goods–but I would believe it would do the same.

You can edit/cancel/update subscriptions right from the subscription module in the CP. Also, there are different notification event triggers for rebills that you should take advantage of too.

Comment: Thanks @Siebird for confirming that Order channel entries are created. I was hoping someone could confirm that the Purchased Items entries are also created... that's a critical part of our order fulfillment process.

Comment: Just run a test to check that. Make a subscription, then go into the `exp_cartthrob_subscriptions` table and manually change the `start_date` to over a month ago (unix timestamp) and then manually run the subscriptions through the CT Admin > Subscriptions > Process Subscriptions button